# VisualBrush of geometry DrawingImage is blurry and cut off

Tags: wpf, xaml, vector-graphics

I would like to draw circular geometry in `VisualBrush` (in order to create an `OpacityMask`), the result however are of rather low quality:

[image]

This image is 500% zoomed in but the cut off of the circle  is apparent (especially on top and bottom) and even at original size the mask is rather blurry. The image was generated with following code:

```
<Border Background="Blue">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <VisualBrush TileMode="None" Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Image>
                    <Image.Source>
                        <DrawingImage>
                            <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="0,0" RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing>
                            </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        </DrawingImage>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
</Border>
```

How can I fix the mask so that is neither blurry nor cut off?

Answer (score 1):

This may be better. At least it is simpler.

```
<Border Background="Blue">
    <Border.OpacityMask>
        <DrawingBrush Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentX="Center" AlignmentY="Center">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="Black">
                    <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        <EllipseGeometry RadiusX="1" RadiusY="1" />
                    </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                </GeometryDrawing>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Border.OpacityMask>
</Border>
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely much simpler (especially when I have the drawing as resource), also looks less blurry. It is still being cut off on bottom and top - any ideas how to fix that part? Something like DrawingPadding should fix it - give the mask canvas a bit more space so antialising 'bleeding' is not discarded. but cant figure out how (cant modify drawing itself/the radius due to the way the drawing is provided).

Comment: I can not reproduce the "pixelation" effect at all. What are you eventually doing with that Border element?

Comment: The cut-off effect is more annoying, the pixelation itself might be just faulty interpolation/hinting etc. (wish I could tell it to render vector geometry in higher resolution for hopefully better result). Did not have the chance to test with different monitor. I am placing it within a grid with mouseover changing background.

Comment: The cut-off seems to be just a result of how the pixel coordinates are aligned with the Border element. How does it look if you add some half-pixel margin, i.e. `Margin="0,0.5"`?

Comment: Setting margin is a trouble: `DrawingBrush` does not have a margin, margin on `Border` has no effect on cut-off and with the 'old' way `VisualBrush.Visual`'s `Image` can have a margin but it seems to be ignored completely.